# Focus management behavior in tab and virtual cursor mode

Tags: focus, accessibility, nvda

I have an application which has a main section and a footer. the main section has a tabIndex="-1". The footer holds the copyright thing.The main section further holds some widgets which holds the buttons in a list.When the page loads, the screen reader announces the page load.The body is the default active element. On tab, the focus moves to the first button in the main section.This is the expected behavior. But i don't see this behavior in the virtual cursor mode. So the page loads, the live expression in chrome shows the body as the active element. when i press the down arrow, the screen reader starts reading the footer instead of traversing the dom from up.It entirely skips the main section.Not sure what the issue is. I can't share code as it is proprietary.

I have tried setting the tab index of the main section container to 0.

Expected: the screen reader(in virtual cursor mode/browse mode) NVDA + Chrome should read the dom structure from the top and not skip the main section.
Actual: It skips the main section and directly reads the footer.

Answer (score 0):

You're using roles or semantic HTML elements, I suppose? These have a [profound effect](http://accessibleculture.org/articles/2012/09/aria-widgets-and-focus-forms-mode-support/) on screenreader behavior.

You mentioned that there are buttons in "main" - this might be throwing the screenreader into forms mode, so that the screenreader has nothing to 'read' except button labels, which you get with tabbing. In forms mode, any 'document-like' content will be ignored, unless it's mentioned in an `aria-describedby` attribute.

You should use `tabindex="-1"` sparingly - only in cases when you are going to call `focus()` on that element. It's not clear whether you're doing that. What happens when you remove the tabindex attribute entirely from main?

Also try separating the document part of "main" from the buttons part, with distinct roles for each (e.g. "document" and "application", but there are [others](https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/roles#document_structure_roles_header) you can try).

Comment: Even if it's forms mode, it should take me to the button and not skip an entire main content section. I used tabindex=-1 in a demo html page along with the same roles of main and contentInfo and the screen reader works well there.